# Chart.js : straight lines instead of curves

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Chart.JS to plot a dataset,

However I got a smooth effect !

Here is the curve I've got :

[image]

Here is my code :

```js
function plotChart(data, labels) {

    var lineChartData = {
        "datasets": [{
            "data": data,
            "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
            "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
        }],
        "labels": labels
    };

    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);

}
```

How can I have straight lines instead of curves ?

Thank you

Answer (score 322, accepted):

**Solution for Version 1 (old charts version)**

According to [documentation on chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart)

you can set the 'bezierCurve' in options and pass it in when you create the chart.

```
bezierCurve: false
```

eg:

```js
var options = {
    //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
    bezierCurve : false
};
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData, options);
```

**Update for version 2**

According to updated documentation for Line Configuration in global options

```
Name        Type    Default Description
tension     Number  0.4     Default bezier curve tension. Set to 0 for no bezier curves.
```

eg:

```js
var options = {
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension: 0
        }
    }
};
```

And also directly in the Dataset Structure by setting `lineTension` to 0 (zero).

```
Property        Type    Usage
lineTension     Number  Bezier curve tension of the line. Set to 0 to draw straightlines. 
                        This option is ignored if monotone cubic interpolation is used. 
                        Note This was renamed from 'tension' but the old name still works.
```

An example data object using these attributes is shown below.

```js
var lineChartData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            lineTension: 0,           
            data: data,
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: You need `bezierCurve: false` to get a straight line. true (the default) gives you a (bezier) curve

Comment: With the new v2.0, to do this, you now set `tension:0`.

Comment: acording to [the latest document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling), please use `lineTension` instead of just 'tension'

Answer (score 81):

You can use lineTension option to set the desired curve. Set 0 for straight lines. You can give a number between 0-1

```
data: {
    datasets: [{
        lineTension: 0
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it for me on v2.7.1

Answer (score 20):

Just to complete version compatibility and to add something to this nice thread here:

Still the same with `chart.js` **v3.x.x**
(which is not backwards compatible with **v2.x.x** -- however, `lineTension` stays unchanged within
`data: { datasets: [{ lineTension: ...` )

### LineTension for `chart.js` v3.x.x

Following, you can **Run the snippet** with 10 buttons to play with different lineTensions (**0** to **1**) right here:

```js
// for now, let's assume sample data
let sample_data = {
  "Labels" : [
    "2021-08-02",
    "2021-08-03",
    "2021-08-04",
    "2021-08-05",
    "2021-08-06"
  ],
  "Values": [
    6,
    4,
    3,
    8,
    2
  ]
};


// Draw chart
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: sample_data.Labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'LineTension Sample',
      data: sample_data.Values,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,1)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)',
      fill: true
    }]
  }
});

function lineTension(event) {
  // Redraw the chart with modified lineTension

  // a bit of 'button-cosmetics' here
  // enabling all buttons
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(element => element.disabled = false);
  // disabling the pressed button
  event.target.disabled = true;

  // setting programmatically the 'lineTension' here
  myLineChart.data.datasets[0].lineTension = parseFloat(event.target.dataset.linetension);

  myLineChart.update();
};
```

```css
  button {
    color: blue;
  }
  button:disabled {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<!-- gets you the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.0 -->

<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0" disabled>0</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.1">0.1</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.2">0.2</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.3">0.3</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.4">0.4</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.5">0.5</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.6">0.6</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.7">0.7</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.8">0.8</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="0.9">0.9</button>
<button onclick="lineTension(event)" data-linetension="1">1</button>

<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, linetension did the trick. Strange that no one actually marked this post as answer. Maybe you've written too much info ?

Answer (score 18):

I have used lineTension to set the smoothness of the curve.

> From the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html): lineTension receives a number, Bezier curve tension of the line. Set to 0 to draw straight lines. This option is ignored if monotone cubic interpolation is used.

Just make sure to test with different values how smooth you want the line.

For example:

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Label 1",
      lineTension: 0.2
    }, {
      label: "Stock B",
      lineTension: 0.2
    }

  ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's been updated to `lineTension`. Check the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html).

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Chart.js v3.9.1++ - the `lineTension` property is changed to just `tension`.
[Link to documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have used but not worked for me.

```
var options = {
    //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
    bezierCurve : false
};
```

I have used this and worked for me.

```
let options = {
  tension: 0.1,
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
  y: {
    beginAtZero: true
    }
  }
}

let chartCustom1 = new Chart(ctxCustom1, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: v_labels,
    datasets: []
  },
  options: options
});
```