# Chart.js - Plot line graph with X , Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a simple line graph with x,y coordinates but i'm getting a blank page .

I don't want to set labels , but have them generated automatically from the x,y coordinates. I think chartjs already implements that but my syntax is wrong.

```
var x = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart1"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test",
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                y: 5
            }, {
                x: 5,
                y: 10
            }, {
                x: 8,
                y: 5
            }, {
                x: 15,
                y: 0
            }],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
    }
});
```

Any idea how to fix the code above ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe, what you are looking for, is a **scatter** graph, not **line**.

```js
var x = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart1"), {
   type: 'scatter',
   data: {
      datasets: [{
         label: "Test",
         data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 5
         }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 10
         }, {
            x: 8,
            y: 5
         }, {
            x: 15,
            y: 0
         }],
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: true
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
```

Refer [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html), to learn more about scatter chart.

Comment: Version 2.7.1 doesn't connect the dots on scatter plot, and it makes sense since what the op is trying to do is a line chart, not a scatter. https://jsfiddle.net/sdz2ot42/

Comment: What @EduardoWada said is true. You can however enable the lines by using the setting: showLine: true for the dataset.

Comment: Can we somehow remove the "splines" and connect via straight lines?

Comment: @Tobi - yes, answered there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403510/chart-js-straight-lines-instead-of-curves

Answer (score 3):

my fresh answer:
the x values should be strings.
transform your data this way:

```
data = data.map(
    v=>({y:v.y,x:''+v.x}));
```

i found it by chance.
the labels array isn't needed.

to use the numeric values of x,
and arrange the labels and points according to their numeric values,
you can use the linear scale type
for the x-axis as follows:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'linear',
    },
  },
}
```

in this case, the mapping of the function above is not needed.