# Chart.js - Plot line graph with X , Y coordinates and connected by line

Tags: chart.js

Basically the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098211/chart-js-plot-line-graph-with-x-y-coordinates) main difference being that I need to connect my points. Is there a way to use X and Y and still have it be a line graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry figured it out since it wasn't intuitive in the docs I will leave this up with an answer.

The default for the `showLine` prop on scatter is false and true on line. Once I changed to true it worked.

so I added `showLine:true` to my datasets