# How to use computed property with data from JSON in data object for time axis in Vue using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to create a chart with a time axis in Vue using Chart.js. When I set the data right in the Data object like so, everything works correctly:

```
chartData: {
    datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: '#ED645A',
            borderColor: '#ED645A',
            fill: false,
            data: [
                {
                    t: new Date("1998-1-1"),
                    y: 7.1
                },
                {
                    t: new Date("1998-2-1"),
                    y: 8.4
                },
                {
                    t: new Date("1998-3-1"),
                    y: 18.5
                },
                {
                    t: new Date("1998-4-1"),
                    y: 16.2
                },
                {
                    t: new Date("1998-5-1"),
                    y: 18.4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

But when I'm trying to load the data from JSON and form the datasets object in computed property, like so, it doesn't work:

```
import pureSecondDatasetJson from "../assets/pureSecondDataset.json"

...

export default {

...

data () {
    return {
        pureSecondDataset: pureSecondDatasetJson,
        charts: [
            chartData: {
            datasets: this.foo
},

...

computed: {
    foo() {
        var plotData = []
        for (var i=0; i<this.pureSecondDataset.length; i++) {        
            plotData.push({t: new Date(this.pureSecondDataset[i].t), y: this.pureSecondDataset[i].y})
        }
        var chartData = [
            {
                backgroundColor: '#ED645A',
                borderColor: '#ED645A',
                fill: false,
                data: plotData
            }
        ];
        return chartData
    }
}
```

The object, created in computed seems the same as the one, which put directly, so why it doesn;t work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try access a computed property from your data as explained on the [Vue Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/computed-properties-in-data/11231/2).

> the data is evaluated before the computed array

I would advise changing your computed property to something like below and then use that as your chart data:

```
foo() {
    var plotData = []
    for (var i=0; i<this.pureSecondDataset.length; i++)        
        plotData.push({t: new Date(this.pureSecondDataset[i].t), y: this.pureSecondDataset[i].y})

    return {
        chartData: {
            datasets:[{
                backgroundColor: '#ED645A',
                borderColor: '#ED645A',
                fill: false,
                data: plotData
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a fiddle to show how you can do this by not using the computed property in data. While I was making the fiddle I found that for a proper line graph you need to have a labels property for the x-values otherwise you can use type: scatter and drawLine:true to specify the x and y values together. [Chart.js - Plot line graph with X , Y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098211/chart-js-plot-line-graph-with-x-y-coordinates)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      plotData: [{
        x: 1,
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 2
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 3
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    foo() {
      return {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            showLine: true,
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: this.plotData
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, this.foo);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<div id="app">
  <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, maybe I don't understand you entirely, but as it seems to me, your solution doesn't change the further usage of computed property. I mean I still have to use it the data function because chart js parameters are setting there

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fiddle showing that you shouldn't have to use computed in data. Hope this helps.

Comment: In your example you set dataset as static object in the data section, but I need to make it with data from JSON via loop

Comment: You can just replace this.plotData with pureSecondDatasetJson.map(x => { t: new Date(x.t), y: x.y });